# Is using client aware GRPCs good idea?

Tags: authentication, client-server, grpc

Consider we have 3 services.

- **A** has public API (Rest) and will call by user from external.
- **B** is internal service which worked independently. **B** acts as a `grpc` server.
- **O** OAuth server and even can validate tokens via `grpc`.

Now,
**A** should call **B** sometimes. this calls does not depends on user but they are depended on **A** itself.

**B** needs to know which service called it. It uses `Authorization` metadata (header) and pass it to ClientResolve service.

ClientResolve service validates `Authorization` header value (token) via **O** and extracts token's client id. (Or maybe uses some internal implementation such as client table in **B** and basic authentication token.)

Is it really good idea? Does this design works correctly? Has any conflict with standards or patterns?